# Upload video with subtitle

Tags: java, youtube, google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

How can I upload video with the subtitle using Youtube Data API v3?

The documentation doesn't [mention](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert) anything.

For uploading, I'm using the sample code with the code bellow:

```
VideoContentDetails contentDetails = new VideoContentDetails();
contentDetails.setCaption("00:00:00.105,00:00:05.413\nSubtitle 1\n\n00:00:05.667,00:00:08.750\nSubtitle 2");
videoObjectDefiningMetadata.setContentDetails(contentDetails);
```

I used the format of the caption, according with [this description from Youtube Data v2.](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_captions#Supported_Caption_File_Formats)

But when I try to upload :

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 400 Bad Request
{
  "code" : 400,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Invalid value for: (.....) is not a valid value",
    "reason" : "invalid"
  } ],
  "message" : "Invalid value for: (.....) is not a valid value"
}
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:145)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:423)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:343)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:46)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no Caption support on Data API v3 right now. (the one you are trying in your code)

You can only set caption via v2, till v3 support is built.

So after uploading your video with v3 as you did above, you can use the same id to call v2 api as in https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_captions#Create_Caption_Track